# SymPy: collecting specific terms in an expression

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to linearize a symbolic expression, like the one given in [SymPy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#collect) for the `collect` function: `a*x**2 + b*x**2 + a*x - b*x + c`. I want to substitute `x` for `x+dx`, and then collect all the terms that are linear in `dx`. But when I try the `collect` function with `coeff` function it does not give me the required answer:

```
>>> from sympy import S, collect, expand, factor, Wild
>>> from sympy.abc import a, b, c, x, y, z
>>> collect(a*x**2 + b*x**2 + a*x - b*x + c, x)
c+x2(a+b)+x(a−b)

>>> eq1 = a*x**2 + b*x**2 + a*x - b*x + c
>>> dx = symbols('dx')
>>> eq2=eq1.subs(x,x+dx)
>>> eq2
a*(dx+x)**2+a*(dx+x)+b*(dx+x)**2−b*(dx+x)+c

>>> collect(eq2,dx).coeff(dx,1)
0
```

Using `Poly` function yields:

```
>>> Poly(eq2,dx)
Poly((a+b)*dx**2+(2*a*x+a+2*b*x−b)*dx+a*x**2+a*x+b*x**2−b*x+c,dx,domain=Z[x,a,b,c])
```

Meaning that the expression that I would like to obtain is `2ax+a+2bx−b`.

Answer (score 1):

The `collect` docstring indicates that

> The input expression is not expanded by :func:`collect`, so user is
>   expected to provide an expression is an appropriate form. This makes
>   :`collect` more predictable as there is no magic happening behind the
>   scenes.

Since there are no terms in which `dx` is a factor -- it appears as a `x + dx` -- the expression should be expanded first:

```
>>> var('a:c dx')
(a, b, c, dx)
>>> eq1 = a*x**2 + b*x**2 + a*x - b*x + c
>>> eqdx = eq1.subs(x, x + dx)
>>> eqdx.expand().coeff(dx)
2*a*x + a + 2*b*x - b
>>> collect(_, (a, b))
a*(2*x + 1) + b*(2*x - 1)
```

Note that it is not necessary to collect in order to get the coefficient...but you do have to expand first.